# Ionic 2 tabs and sidebar - How do I maintain tabs with setRoot?

Tags: tabs, navigation, ionic2

I have an Ionic 2 app that uses both a sidebar and tabs.

I have managed to create a link in the sidebar that sends the user back to the root page, but this kills the tabs. I would like the tabs to be persistent.

Here is what I have:

**app.html**

```
`<ion-menu [content]="content">
   <ion-toolbar>
     <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
   </ion-toolbar>

  <ion-content>
   <ion-list>
     <ion-item (click)="openPage(page)" *ngFor="let page of pages">
      <span>{{page.title}}</span>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

```
<ion-nav id="nav" [root]="rootPage" #content swipe-back-enabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

Then in my app.ts I have this function:

```
openPage(page) {
  this.menu.close();
  this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
}
```

So this does actually work, but I lose my tabs. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Hey, did you find a solution? Old question already, but i'm facing the same problem right now ;).

Answer (score 1):

```
this.nav.setRoot(TabsPage);
```

TabsPage is the class name of your tabs page's component.

Answer (score -1):

You could reference the [ionic-conference-app](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-conference-app/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts). It works for me.

```
  openPage(page){
    this.menu.close();
    let params = {};
    if (page.index) {
      params = { tabIndex: page.index };
    }
    if (this.nav.getActiveChildNavs().length && page.index != undefined) {
      this.nav.getActiveChildNavs()[0].select(page.index);
    } else {
      this.nav.setRoot(page.name, params).catch((err: any) => {
        console.log(`Didn't set nav root: ${err}`);
      });
    }
  }
```